# URL masquerade in IIS 7+ for address bar

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a client who has a domain: `www.domain-name.com`

This runs on IIS with an ASP.NET MVC 2 application. There are also custom layout pages for his own clients.

My client wants to buy another domain, say `www.mybestclient-name.com`.

If you browse to this domain the content should come from `www.domain-name.com`, **but** in the address bar only `www.mybestclient-name.com` should displayed.

There should also be no path in the URL either, i.e. `/index` should not be shown.

Is this possible with IIS 7.x and if yes then how?

My first guess was NO for security reasons, because I think it's similar to phishing. I don't like use the word "impossible" when I talk with a client ;-).

Answer (score 0):

- Bind `mybestclient-name.com` as CNAME to `domain-name.com`
- Add entry to IIS bindings, saying any ip with header `mybestclient-name.com`, `www.mybestclient-name.com`, etc

Comment: Thanks, for the fast response. I'll try it out and reply later.